# change app.components style from different component in angular 2

Tags: angular, styles

I'm trying to change the app.component.html style from another component. 
I'm my app.component.html I have a  I'm using an object with lots of properties for the style.

When a button is clicked from component2 and toggleLayout() is called, this.Data.xmldata.uiStyle[0]['$']['styleForUI'] = "styleLayout2"; will change the shared variable, but app.component doesn't know when the shared variable is changed.

Is this process too indirect, should I be trying to call a method in app.component.ts from outside?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should avoid directly calling component's methods if you can, to reduce coupling. You can use a shared service based on observables.

**service**

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Observable, Subject} from "rxjs";


@Injectable()
export class MessageService
{
  private mySubject: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();
  public readonly stylesChanged$: Observable<any> = this.mySubject.asObservable();


  brodcastStylesChanged(styles)
  {
    this.mySubject.next(styles );
  }
}
```

**component2**

```
this.messageService.brodcastStylesChanged(styles);
```

**component1**

```
this.messageService.stylesChanged$.subscribe(styles=> {
    this.styles= styles;
});
```

Comment: @Mark Don't forget to unsubscribe when the component is destroyed though