# Is parent to parent communication is possible in angular 5 using Subject or Behaviour Subject

Tags: angular, angular5, behaviorsubject, subject-observer

Is parent to parent communication is possible in angular 5 using Subject or Behaviour Subject. For example: ListComponent and DetailComponent. Both are different component and views. When i clicked save data of a form in ListComponent, it should routed to the DetailComponent page. Then display the data in the edit form.

I aware parent to child or child to parent is possible. But my scenario is parent to parent. Like when we call .next. It should give the data in next page also. This is like passing json object in between different components. If this is not working, the only option is setting localStorage and retrieve in the next page.

This may be a wrong question, but if any possible way will be helpful.

Comment: it is possible through service but the service should be shared

Comment: See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49820822/change-app-components-style-from-different-component-in-angular-2

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible. Include a `shared service` in both the components and `subscribe` in both the components

Comment: Thanks all for the reply. The suggestion worked for me. The code with clear explanation is here - https://scotch.io/tutorials/get-angular-1-features-in-angular-2#global-communication-with-services

Comment: Glad it helped you